# MS Graph API - How to get sharepoint authorization levels

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm use MS Graph API for check permissions of Sharepoint site, drives and items. I manage to recover all informations except a name of permission level.
I have a response format (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/permission?view=graph-rest-1.0):

```
{
  "id": "string (identifier)",
  "grantedTo": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.identitySet"},
  "grantedToIdentities": [{"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.identitySet"}],
  "grantedToV2": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.sharePointIdentitySet"},
  "grantedToIdentitiesV2": [{"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.sharePointIdentitySet"}],
  "inheritedFrom": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.itemReference"},
  "invitation": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.sharingInvitation"},
  "link": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.sharingLink"},
  "roles": ["string"],
  "shareId": "string",
  "expirationDateTime": "string (timestamp)",
  "hasPassword": "boolean"
}
```

Roles values are

- "write"
- "owner"
- "read"
- ""

How retry a permission level (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels)?

- Full Control
- Contribute
- Restricted Read
- ...

My request format: GET /drive/items/{item-id}/permissions

Does anyone have a solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

Per my research, currently there is no such function to get users permission in site by graph. We can only use /sites/{sitesId}/permissions but the resource only returns permissions granted to the Azure Apps. The api doesn't return the users in the site. Here is a similar issue with yours

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292435/list-permissions-for-sharepoint-sites-using-graphapi

This is my test result
[image]